# Python Selenium find element by link text contains a string with wildcard or regex

Tags: python, regex, selenium

I have a HTML snippet like this:

```
<span class="line S_line1">
  评论
  <em>1</em>
</span>
```

The thing is that number in `<em>1</em>` is not predictable or sometime just omit, I want to find this element by

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text(u'评论*')
```

But it didn't work, is there a way to do that with a wildcard or regex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(u'评论')
```

You can using `partial_link_text`.This way you can find a link with changing content using some part which is always constant.